# Failed to mark transaction as rollback only in Neo4J Junit

Tags: java, junit, spring-data-neo4j

I have been trying to setup my test framework for `Spring data neo4j (version 3.0.1.RELEASE)` application. I am using pure java config to setup my test cases.

This is my TestConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = {"com.sitename.data.repository"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sitename.data")
public class TestDataConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate() {
        return new Neo4jTemplate(graphDatabaseService());
    }

}
```

And this is my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class TestClass {

    private UserService userService = UserService.getInstance();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        BaseService.configure(TestDataConfig.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void addData() {
        saveOneUser("test@email.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        Assert.assertEquals(0, userService.findAll().size());
    }

    private User saveOneUser(String email) {
        try {
            User user = new User();
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setFirstName( new Integer(new Random(new Date().getTime()).nextInt(17) + 1).toString() );
            return userService.save( user );
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Every time i run the test i am getting the `Failed to mark transaction as rollback only` error.

Full stacktrace

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.sitename.TestClass
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.416 sec <<< FAILURE!
testMe(com.sitename.TestClass)  Time elapsed: 0.406 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Failed to mark transaction as rollback only.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.markAsRollbackOnly(TopLevelTransaction.java:97)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.failure(TopLevelTransaction.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_0.TransactionBoundExecutionContext.close(TransactionBoundExecutionContext.scala:58)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.DelegatingQueryContext.close(DelegatingQueryContext.scala:32)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$spi$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$super$close(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$anonfun$close$1.apply$mcV$sp(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$anonfun$close$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$anonfun$close$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$spi$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$translateException(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:149)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.close(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:34)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.ClosingIterator.failIfThrows(ClosingIterator.scala:94)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.ClosingIterator.next(ClosingIterator.scala:45)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.PipeExecutionResult.next(PipeExecutionResult.scala:168)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.PipeExecutionResult.next(PipeExecutionResult.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:30)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.PipeExecutionResult$$anon$1.next(PipeExecutionResult.scala:76)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.next(IteratorWrapper.java:47)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.next(IteratorWrapper.java:47)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.addToCollection(IteratorUtil.java:478)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil.addToCollection(IteratorUtil.java:557)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.ContainerConverter.toContainer(ContainerConverter.java:34)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.QueryResultBuilder$1.as(QueryResultBuilder.java:128)
    at com.sitename.data.service.UserService.findAll(UserService.java:20)
    at com.sitename.TestClass.testMe(TestClass.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.markAsRollbackOnly(TopLevelTransaction.java:93)
    ... 60 more
```

Help is appreciated. TIA !

Answer (score 0):

Try and add

```
@Transactional
```

on top of your test class to run your tests within a transaction.